# Possible Null Value Cells In csv File

Tags: python, database, string, numpy, integer

Good evening,

May I please get advice on a section of code that I have? Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import logging
#logging.getLogger('tensorflow').setLevel(logging.ERROR)


os.chdir('/media/Maps/test_run/')
coasts_data='new_coastline_combined.csv'

coasts = pd.read_csv(coasts_data, header=None, encoding='latin1')

#Combine all data into a single frame

frames = [coasts] 
df = pd.concat(frames)

n = 1000  #chunk row size
list_df = [df[i:i+n] for i in range(0,df.shape[0],n)]

l=[]
for index, frame in enumerate(list_df):
    vals = frame.iloc[:,2].values

    vals = eval(vals)
    # if any values in this part of the frame are wrong, store index for deletion
    if np.any(vals < -100000):
         l.append(index)
for x in sorted(l, reverse=True):
    del list_df[x]

df1 = pd.concat(list_df)
df1.to_csv(r'/media/test_run_6/test.csv',index=False,header=False)
```

What the code does is take data from a csv file, break it into groups of 1000 rows each, determine if erroneous values are present, and delete that group of data. It works fine on most csv files. However, on one csv file, I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

The error begins at this section of code:

> if np.any(vals < -100000):

I suspect (and please correct me if I'm wrong) that there are null (empty) cells in this particular column of values inside the csv (the csv is 6,000,000 rows deep, btw).

May I please get help on finding out what the problem is and how to fix it? Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I recommend catching the error to find out which line it is causing it and then manually check what problem has occured in your data.

Something like this:

```
try:
    if np.any(vals < -100000):
         l.append(index)
except TypeError:
    print(vals)
    print(index)
```

If it's really just a empty cells you could check that and ignore these cells.